# Can't upgrade "Android SDK Platform-tools"

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating android studio to 0.6.0 I get

Error:Cause: failed to find Build Tools revision 19.1.0
Please install the missing Build Tools from the Android SDK Manager.

I try to update "Android SDK Platform-tools" to 19.1.0 but android sdk manager doesn't offer me any update.

[image]

Comment: If you already have 19.1.0 installed, you may just need to update your `build.gradle` file

Comment: I cannot see Platform Tools 19.1.0 as an update either - but it is available to be checked manually. Hope checking and installing this version manually solves your problem.

Comment: Just to avoid some confusion, `build tools and platform tools are decoupled and not the same`, upgrading one does not necessarily mean the other one is updated.

Comment: @Andrew Schuster No I can't upgrade it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isnt an update, it is a new version- in the "rev" column of the SDK manager look for the 19.1 version, its definitely there. Check it and download it. I did exact same thing this morning.

**You want Android SDK Build-Tools rev 19.1**

Comment: No it's not there. Check the picture I added

Comment: its right there on the picture, it says its not installed. just install the 19.1 version.

Comment: You want Android SDK Build Tools rev 19.1

Answer (score 2):

19.1 is the third one down in your list. It says "Not installed" on the image you posted. Tick it and install. It is not an update of another package.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. Didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and finally realized that the Eclipse and the Android Studio use ***two different copies of the SDK***. When I updated the right copy, well, I found another problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by unChecking "SDKManager --> tools --> force https://... sources to be fetching..." and reload packages. Give a try